# Extraer datos de un Textarea con javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Estoy desarrollando una función que trabaja sobre el contenido de un textarea mediante javascript, pero me estoy volviendo loco porque cuando el array parrafo[4] entra en juego la pagina se bloquea y no ejecuta el resto del codigo

el codigo es este:

```
function myFunction() {
                            
                        
    var texto = document.getElementById("textarea").value;//Capturamos el textarea
    var longitud = texto.length; //Averiguamos longitud del texto
    //alert("La longitud del texto es "+longitud);

    //SEPARAMOS EL TEXTO POR PARRAFOS Y AVERIGUAMOS Nº ARTICULO Y TITULO
    //texto = texto.replace('\n\n','\n');
    var parrafo = texto.split ("\n"); //extraemos los parrafos
    var cantidaddeparrafos = parrafo.length; //contamos los parrafos
    alert("Cantidad de parrafos: "+cantidaddeparrafos);
    var parrafoparaintroducir = "";
    var i=0;
    alert ("Parrafoc on valo i4= "+parrafo[4]);
    while(i <= cantidaddeparrafos) {//Buscamos por cada Parrafo
        alert ("i al inicio= "+i);//entra con 0
        alert ("Parrafo con valo i4= "+parrafo[4]);
        if (parrafo[i].startsWith('Artículo ') == true){// Si el parrafo empieza con Artículo

            var palabrasparrafo = parrafo[i].split(" ");
            var numeroarticulo = palabrasparrafo[1];//Capturamos el nº de articulo
            if (numeroarticulo.charAt(numeroarticulo.length - 1) == "." ){//Si termina en punto, lo eliminamos
                numeroarticulo = numeroarticulo.substr(0, numeroarticulo.length - 1);
                alert ("El numero del articulo es: "+numeroarticulo);
                }

            if  (palabrasparrafo[2] != "\n"){ //Averiguamos si el articulo tiene titulo
            var tituloarticulo = palabrasparrafo.slice(2).join(" ");
            alert ("El titulo del articulo es: "+tituloarticulo);
            }   
            parrafoparaintroducir = "";

        }else{

            while (parrafo[i].startsWith('Artículo') == false){//Unimos los parrafos que no empiezan por Artículo
            parrafoparaintroducir = parrafoparaintroducir+"\n"+parrafo[i];
            i++;
            }
            i--;

        if (parrafoparaintroducir != ""){
            alert ("El parrafo del articulo es: "+parrafoparaintroducir);
            }

        }
         i++;
        alert ("i al final= "+i);       
    }//Fin For

    }
```

Estoy intentando que extraiga por un lado el numero del articulo, el titulo del artículo si lo tiene y el contenido del articulo para introducirlo en una base de datos.

Lo que hago es separar el texto en párrafos, para después en relación a su primera palabra, separar el numero del articulo, el titulo, y el contenido uniendo todos los párrafos de este artículo.

El texto que estoy utilizando de prueba es este:

Artículo 1. Objeto de la Ley.

1. La presente Ley tiene por objeto regular los requisitos de validez y eficacia de los actos administrativos, el procedimiento administrativo común a todas las Administraciones Públicas, incluyendo el sancionador y el de reclamación de responsabilidad de las Administraciones Públicas, así como los principios a los que se ha de ajustar el ejercicio de la iniciativa legislativa y la potestad reglamentaria.
2. Solo mediante ley, cuando resulte eficaz, proporcionado y necesario para la consecución de los fines propios del procedimiento, y de manera motivada, podrán incluirse trámites adicionales o distintos a los contemplados en esta Ley. Reglamentariamente podrán establecerse especialidades del procedimiento referidas a los órganos competentes, plazos propios del concreto procedimiento por razón de la materia, formas de iniciación y terminación, publicación e informes a recabar.

Artículo 2. Ámbito subjetivo de aplicación.

1. La presente Ley se aplica al sector público, que comprende:

a) La Administración General del Estado.

b) Las Administraciones de las Comunidades Autónomas.

c) Las Entidades que integran la Administración Local.

d) El sector público institucional.

2. El sector público institucional se integra por:

a) Cualesquiera organismos públicos y entidades de derecho público vinculados o dependientes de las Administraciones Públicas.

b) Las entidades de derecho privado vinculadas o dependientes de las Administraciones Públicas, que quedarán sujetas a lo dispuesto en las normas de esta Ley que específicamente se refieran a las mismas, y en todo caso, cuando ejerzan potestades administrativas.

c) Las Universidades públicas, que se regirán por su normativa específica y supletoriamente por las previsiones de esta Ley.

3. Tienen la consideración de Administraciones Públicas la Administración General del Estado, las Administraciones de las Comunidades Autónomas, las Entidades que integran la Administración Local, así como los organismos públicos y entidades de derecho público previstos en la letra a) del apartado 2 anterior.
4. Las Corporaciones de Derecho Público se regirán por su normativa específica en el ejercicio de las funciones públicas que les hayan sido atribuidas por Ley o delegadas por una Administración Pública, y supletoriamente por la presente Ley

Podéis echarle un ojo al código. Muchas gracias

```js
function myFunction() {
                                
                            
        var texto = document.getElementById("textarea").value;//Capturamos el textarea
        var longitud = texto.length; //Averiguamos longitud del texto
        //alert("La longitud del texto es "+longitud);

        //SEPARAMOS EL TEXTO POR PARRAFOS Y AVERIGUAMOS Nº ARTICULO Y TITULO
        //texto = texto.replace('\n\n','\n');
        var parrafo = texto.split ("\n"); //extraemos los parrafos
        var cantidaddeparrafos = parrafo.length; //contamos los parrafos
        alert("Cantidad de parrafos: "+cantidaddeparrafos);
        var parrafoparaintroducir = "";
        var i=0;
        alert ("Parrafoc on valo i4= "+parrafo[4]);
        while(i <= cantidaddeparrafos) {//Buscamos por cada Parrafo
            alert ("i al inicio= "+i);//entra con 0
            alert ("Parrafo con valo i4= "+parrafo[4]);
            if (parrafo[i].startsWith('Artículo ') == true){// Si el parrafo empieza con Artículo

                var palabrasparrafo = parrafo[i].split(" ");
                var numeroarticulo = palabrasparrafo[1];//Capturamos el nº de articulo
                if (numeroarticulo.charAt(numeroarticulo.length - 1) == "." ){//Si termina en punto, lo eliminamos
                    numeroarticulo = numeroarticulo.substr(0, numeroarticulo.length - 1);
                    alert ("El numero del articulo es: "+numeroarticulo);
                    }

                if  (palabrasparrafo[2] != "\n"){ //Averiguamos si el articulo tiene titulo
                var tituloarticulo = palabrasparrafo.slice(2).join(" ");
                alert ("El titulo del articulo es: "+tituloarticulo);
                }   
                parrafoparaintroducir = "";

            }else{

                while (parrafo[i].startsWith('Artículo') == false){//Unimos los parrafos que no empiezan por Artículo
                parrafoparaintroducir = parrafoparaintroducir+"\n"+parrafo[i];
                i++;
                }
                i--;

            if (parrafoparaintroducir != ""){
                alert ("El parrafo del articulo es: "+parrafoparaintroducir);
                }

            }
             i++;
            alert ("i al final= "+i);       
        }//Fin For

        }
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Leave a comment here" id="textarea" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Obtener caracteres</button>
```

Comment: Echando un vistazo rápido veo que:  Usando "palabrasparrafo[2]" y "parrafo[4] estas dando por supuesto que existen. En  while(i <= cantidaddeparrafos) te pasas de largo una posición, ya que estos comienzan en la posicion 0, si cantidad=10, van de 0 a 9, así que debería ser  while(i < cantidaddeparrafos).
Además luego veo que haces ciertas modificaciones con la cantidad de parrafos, que deben ser incorrectos, ya que el código lanza el error "parrafo[i] is undefined"

Comment: Entiendo lo del while, esta cambiado.  Incluyo "i--;" porque me salta un parrafo cuando sale del While. Puede que el error esté ahí pero no se muy bien como hacerlo.

Comment: Creo que el problema está a la hora de contar los parrafos y los numeros del array generados al hacer el split en texto.

Answer (score 1):

Conseguido!!
He tenido que usar un contador de array y un contador de parrafos separados, además de incluir un break en el while ya que entraba en conflicto cuando i era mayor que el numero real del array.

No sé si el código es lo más limpio de todo, pero, lo dejo aqui por si interesa:

```
        function myFunction() {
                            
                        
    var texto = document.getElementById("textarea").value;//Capturamos el textarea
    var longitud = texto.length; //Averiguamos longitud del texto

    //SEPARAMOS EL TEXTO POR PARRAFOS Y AVERIGUAMOS Nº ARTICULO Y TITULO
    texto = texto.replace('\n\n','\n');
    var parrafo = texto.split ("\n"); //extraemos los parrafos
    var cantidaddeparrafos = parrafo.length; //contamos los parrafos
    alert("Cantidad de parrafos: "+cantidaddeparrafos);
    var parrafoparaintroducir = "";
    var i=0;//contador de array
    var c=1;//contador numero de parrafos
    while(c <= cantidaddeparrafos) {//Buscamos por cada Parrafo
        
        if (parrafo[i].startsWith('Artículo ') == true){// Si el parrafo empieza con Artículo

            var palabrasparrafo = parrafo[i].split(" ");
            var numeroarticulo = palabrasparrafo[1];//Capturamos el nº de articulo
            if (numeroarticulo.charAt(numeroarticulo.length - 1) == "." ){//Si termina en punto, lo eliminamos
                numeroarticulo = numeroarticulo.substr(0, numeroarticulo.length - 1);
                alert ("El numero del articulo es: "+numeroarticulo);
                }else{//Si no termina en punto lo dejamos como está
                alert ("El numero del articulo es: "+numeroarticulo);
                }

            if  (palabrasparrafo[2] != null){ //Averiguamos si el articulo tiene titulo
            var tituloarticulo = palabrasparrafo.slice(2).join(" ");
            alert ("El titulo del articulo es: "+tituloarticulo);
            }else{
            alert ("El artículo no tiene título");
            }   
            parrafoparaintroducir = "";
            i++;
            c++;
        }else{

            while (parrafo[i].startsWith('Artículo') == false){//Unimos los parrafos que no empiezan por Artículo
            parrafoparaintroducir = parrafoparaintroducir+"\n"+parrafo[i];
            i++;
            c++;
                if(parrafo[i]==null){
                    break;
                }
            }
        
        }
        
        if (parrafoparaintroducir != ""){
            alert ("El parrafo del articulo es: "+parrafoparaintroducir);
            }

    }//Fin del primer While
    
}
```

```js
        function myFunction() {
                                
                            
        var texto = document.getElementById("textarea").value;//Capturamos el textarea
        var longitud = texto.length; //Averiguamos longitud del texto

        //SEPARAMOS EL TEXTO POR PARRAFOS Y AVERIGUAMOS Nº ARTICULO Y TITULO
        texto = texto.replace('\n\n','\n');
        var parrafo = texto.split ("\n"); //extraemos los parrafos
        var cantidaddeparrafos = parrafo.length; //contamos los parrafos
        alert("Cantidad de parrafos: "+cantidaddeparrafos);
        var parrafoparaintroducir = "";
        var i=0;//contador de array
        var c=1;//contador numero de parrafos
        while(c <= cantidaddeparrafos) {//Buscamos por cada Parrafo
            
            if (parrafo[i].startsWith('Artículo ') == true){// Si el parrafo empieza con Artículo

                var palabrasparrafo = parrafo[i].split(" ");
                var numeroarticulo = palabrasparrafo[1];//Capturamos el nº de articulo
                if (numeroarticulo.charAt(numeroarticulo.length - 1) == "." ){//Si termina en punto, lo eliminamos
                    numeroarticulo = numeroarticulo.substr(0, numeroarticulo.length - 1);
                    alert ("El numero del articulo es: "+numeroarticulo);
                    }else{//Si no termina en punto lo dejamos como está
                    alert ("El numero del articulo es: "+numeroarticulo);
                    }

                if  (palabrasparrafo[2] != null){ //Averiguamos si el articulo tiene titulo
                var tituloarticulo = palabrasparrafo.slice(2).join(" ");
                alert ("El titulo del articulo es: "+tituloarticulo);
                }else{
                alert ("El artículo no tiene título");
                }   
                parrafoparaintroducir = "";
                i++;
                c++;
            }else{

                while (parrafo[i].startsWith('Artículo') == false){//Unimos los parrafos que no empiezan por Artículo
                parrafoparaintroducir = parrafoparaintroducir+"\n"+parrafo[i];
                i++;
                c++;
                    if(parrafo[i]==null){
                        break;
                    }
                }
            
            }
            
            if (parrafoparaintroducir != ""){
                alert ("El parrafo del articulo es: "+parrafoparaintroducir);
                }

        }//Fin del primer While
        
    }
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Leave a comment here" id="textarea" style="height: 100px"></textarea>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Obtener datos</button>
```